vscode jupyter notebook kernel crashes when running polars code
In VSCode, Created a new python project with a new Virtual environment. pip installed the polars package and executed a sample polars code from https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/getting-started/. However the kernel is crashing repeatedly, if the code is executed. Please advice.
pip install polars


import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "integer": [1, 2, 3],
        "date": [
            datetime(2025, 1, 1),
            datetime(2025, 1, 2),
            datetime(2025, 1, 3),
        ],
        "float": [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        "string": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)

print(df)



The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. 
Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. 
Click <a href='https://aka.ms/vscodeJupyterKernelCrash'>here</a> for more info. 
View Jupyter log for further details.


Adding further diagnostics from terminal...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(.venv) D:\zikzakjack\code\vscodes\playground_polars>pip install polars
Requirement already satisfied: polars in d:\zikzakjack\code\vscodes\playground_polars\.venv\lib\site-packages (1.6.0)

(.venv) D:\zikzakjack\code\vscodes\playground_polars>python
Python 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import polars as pl
d:\zikzakjack\code\vscodes\playground_polars\.venv\Lib\site-packages\polars\_cpu_check.py:259: RuntimeWarning: Missing required CPU features.

The following required CPU features were not detected:
    avx2, fma, bmi1, bmi2, lzcnt, movbe
Continuing to use this version of Polars on this processor will likely result in a crash.
Install the `polars-lts-cpu` package instead of `polars` to run Polars with better compatibility.

    avx2, fma, bmi1, bmi2, lzcnt, movbe
Continuing to use this version of Polars on this processor will likely result in a crash.
Install the `polars-lts-cpu` package instead of `polars` to run Polars with better compatibility.

Hint: If you are on an Apple ARM machine (e.g. M1) this is likely due to running Python under Rosetta.
It is recommended to install a native version of Python that does not run under Rosetta x86-64 emulation.

If you believe this warning to be a false positive, you can set the `POLARS_SKIP_CPU_CHECK` environment variable to bypass this check.

  warnings.warn(


Is there anything in the Jupyter log the error message mentions?

23:19:17.234 [info] Process Execution: d:\zikzakjack\code\vscodes\playground_polars.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --f=c:\Users~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v3fbe3d491b70716ceb9d592ed534d583381b08d4f.json
> cwd: d:\zikzakjack\code\vscodes\playground_polars
23:19:18.745 [info] Restarted 32da1dbc-397a-44a9-8bbb-29bf6c12f570
23:19:25.276 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221225501, Reason:

Issue is because of Polars performing a cpu check. Mine is a way Old ASUS RoG Gaming Laptop bought in 2012. Thats possibly tripping some polars cpu check. Refer the link for more details: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15404. Solution is to uninstall the polars package and use the polars-lts-cpu. I hope this solution helps someone with older cpu as mine.
step1: pip uninstall polars
step2: pip install polars-lts-cpu
Screenshot of working demo:

Further debugging based on suggestion from @orlp
current packages list
(venv_polars) D:\zikzakjack\venvs\venv_polars>pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        24.0
pyspark    3.5.2
setuptools 65.5.0

polars will not be available. fails as expected
(venv_polars) D:\zikzakjack\venvs\venv_polars>python
Python 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import polars as pl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polars'
>>>

pip install polars-lts-cpu
(venv_polars) D:\zikzakjack\venvs\venv_polars>pip install polars-lts-cpu
Collecting polars-lts-cpu
  Using cached polars_lts_cpu-1.6.0-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Using cached polars_lts_cpu-1.6.0-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (31.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: polars-lts-cpu
Successfully installed polars-lts-cpu-1.6.0

packages list after install
(venv_polars) D:\zikzakjack\venvs\venv_polars>pip list
Package        Version
-------------- -------
pip            24.0
polars-lts-cpu 1.6.0
pyspark        3.5.2
setuptools     65.5.0

try a polars sample without setting POLARS_SKIP_CPU_CHECK
works properly as indicated by the cpu check author @orlp.
(venv_polars) D:\zikzakjack\venvs\venv_polars>python
Python 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import polars as pl
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "integer": [1, 2, 3],
...         "date": [
...             datetime(2025, 1, 1),
...             datetime(2025, 1, 2),
...             datetime(2025, 1, 3),
...         ],
...         "float": [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
...         "string": ["a", "b", "c"],
...     }
... )
>>>
>>> print(df)
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ integer ┆ date                ┆ float ┆ string │
│ ---     ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64     ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64   ┆ str    │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 2025-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4.0   ┆ a      │
│ 2       ┆ 2025-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 5.0   ┆ b      │
│ 3       ┆ 2025-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 6.0   ┆ c      │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
>>>


As the author of said CPU check, you should not need POLARS_SKIP_CPU_CHECK when using polars-lts-cpu. Can you verify this is the case, and if not tell me what sort of error you are seeing?
It's a bit unfortunate that the notebook doesn't show the error message (which in my opinion is quite clear on the problem and steps to fix it), and it only gets dumped to the terminal. I can see if I can improve on that.

sure, i will try again with a new venv and confirm.
I was setting the variable using the below hint. I have added the diagnostics messages shown in the terminal in original post as well...
Hint: If you are on an Apple ARM machine (e.g. M1) this is likely due to running Python under Rosetta.
It is recommended to install a native version of Python that does not run under Rosetta x86-64 emulation.
If you believe this warning to be a false positive, you can set the POLARS_SKIP_CPU_CHECK environment variable to bypass this check.

@orlp
Polars is functioning correctly using the polars-lts-cpu package without the POLARS_SKIP_CPU_CHECK environment variable set. I've added more information to my response, including detailed logs. Thanks for taking the time to comment and pointing that out.
